# How do I add a Windows Server shared folder to a Raspberry pi?

Tags: fstab, shared-folders

I am working on adding a shared folder to a raspberry pi.

I am trying to add a shared folder to the raspberry pi so we can use it as a kiosk of sorts. We have a file on our server that is recreated every minute. And for the kiosks we were hoping to use raspberry pis to open said folder since it is just an html document.

However, I've had no luck with quite a few different mounting attempts.

My requirements for the project are as follows:

- It must use open the file from the shared folder; it cannot be hosted publicly
- Any solution I find cannot have recurring costs so a program like Screenly wouldn't work. (This is becoming increasingly difficult)
- It must be the cheapest solution I can find. Obviously this probably goes without saying on any project but we were planning on using Intel NUC's which would then have a $250 price tag compared to $35 or ideally a $10 Pi zero.
- The software generating the file must be stored on the server. It is part of how our ERP software functions. It in turn must work with our domain

Things I have tried? Many variations of

```
sudo mount -variable cifs username=username,password=password //shareIP/Sharefolder /home/pi/testdir
```

I have also tried many variations to editing the fstab file.

Answer (score 1):

To mount the Windows share you will need to execute:

```
mount -t cifs //shareIP/Sharefolder /home/pi/testdir -o username=username,password=password,domain=domain
```

Make sure that the /home/pi/testdir is created. If you get errors executing the mount command, you might also need to install cifs-utils.

Comment: I just get `Retrying with upper case share name    mount error(6): No such device or address    Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`